# Creating View in CouchDB with the help of Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am trying to create a view document in CouchDB in erlang language. I have enabled erlang query_server in config. When i am creating the document, the language is being set as javascript and if I go to the design doc and change it to erlang, I am getting an error from CouchDB.

```
fun({Doc}) ->
    case proplists:get_value(<<"type">>, Doc) of
    undefined ->
        ok;
    Type ->
        Identifiers = proplists:get_value(<<"institution">>, Doc),
        lists:foreach(fun(Doc) 
        -> 
        Emit(doc._id,Doc);
    _ ->
        ok
    end.
```

Error found is :

```
Error running query. Reason: ({badmatch,[<<"error">>, {9,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ","'.'"]}, {9,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ","'.'"]}]}) [{couch_query_servers,'-start_doc_map/3-fun-0-',2, [{file,"src/couch_query_servers.erl"},{line,62}]}, {lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1337}]}, {couch_query_servers,start_doc_map,3, [{file,"src/couch_query_servers.erl"},{line,61}]}, {couch_mrview_updater,start_query_server,1, [{file,"src/couch_mrview_updater.erl"},{line,231}]}, {couch_mrview_updater,map_docs,2, [{file,"src/couch_mrview_updater.erl"},{line,184}]}]
```

Answer (score 5):

For the `fun` being passed to `lists:foreach`, you're missing a closing parenthesis, as well as an `end` for the `case`, and an `end` for the enclosing `fun`.  Also, `lists:foreach` takes the list being operated on as its second argument. Try this:

```
fun({Doc}) ->
        case proplists:get_value(<<"type">>, Doc) of
            undefined ->
                ok;
            Type ->
                Identifiers = proplists:get_value(<<"institution">>, Doc),
                lists:foreach(fun(Doc) ->
                                      Emit(doc._id,Doc);
                                 _ ->
                                      ok
                              end,
                              Identifiers) % ← add argument and closing parenthesis here 
        end % ← add 'end' for 'case' here
end. % ← add 'end' for 'fun' here
```

I'm not sure about `Emit(doc._id,Doc)`.  Since `Emit` starts with a capital letter, it refers to a variable, but there is no `Emit` variable here - or does CouchDB make that variable available somehow?  Also `doc._id` is not valid Erlang syntax; I guess it should be `proplists:get_value(<<"_id">>, Doc)`.